# Length of the ranges array in a LaserScan msg

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having this programming problem: I'm cycling through the `ranges` array in `LaserScan` messages and accessing its values. I'm using just this simple for cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(scan->ranges)/sizeof(scan->ranges[0]); i++)
```

But the expression for getting the array length returns the value of `6`, although  the scan contains many more values (seen them through `rostopic echo`). What am I doing wrong? Isn't this the normal way of obtaining the length of an array in C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272487/length-of-the-ranges-array-in-a-laserscan-msg/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2017-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Isn't this the normal way of obtaining the length of an array in C++?

No. What you show is one approach that you could use in C.

> I'm cycling through the `ranges` array in `LaserScan` messages [..]

Note that unbounded arrays in ROS msgs are mapped onto `std::vector` in C++.

If you want to use an old style `for`-loop, you can use `std::vector::size()`. Otherwise an `iterator` is a bit more "C++-y".

---

Refer to [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification) for more information on how ROS msg IDL is mapped onto C++ types.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2017-10-07**:
Oh, it's a vector. I thought it's a normal array. Thanks, now I get it.